# How do I stub a results.map(&:blank_image) in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working on writing tests and I get to this line:

```
blank_images = results.map(&:blank_image)
```

In my test, I am trying to stub it and have it return an array:

```
expect(results).to receive(:map).with(&:blank_image).and_return([true, true, true])
```

I keep getting the message:

```
ArgumentError: `with` must have at least one argument. Use `no_args` matcher to set the expectation of receiving no arguments.
```

How do I pass `&:blank_image` to the `with()` method in Rspec?

**Edit: Also, what is the search term for `&:blank_image` so that I can read more about what this means.

Comment: Try `expect(results).to receive(:map).and_return([true, true, true])` ; `results.map(&:blank_image)` is short-cut for `results.map { |x| x.blank_image }`. So `&:blank_image` isn't really being passed as a variable.

Comment: Try `expect(results).to receive(:map) { |arg| expect(arg).to receive(:blank_image) }.and_return([true, true, true])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
expect(results).to receive(:map). and_yield(a_object_with_blank_image_property). and_yield(aother_object_with_blank_image_property)
```

By referring to: https://makandracards.com/makandra/1321-rspec-stubbing-a-method-that-takes-a-block